# The resource is defined outside of the project and cannot be updated

Tags: android

I am writing an Android app in Android Studio and when I try to rename a TextView, it throws the following error:

```
The resource <B>@id/message</B> is defined outside of the project (in one of the libraries) and cannot be updated. This can change the behavior of the application.<BR/><BR/>Are you sure you want to do this?<BR/><BR/>Unhandled references:<BR/>
```

I've never seen this error before and I can't find any info on it on the internet, so I assume it has something to do with the new 3.6 update, but I don't know what library the error could be talking about. Any help is appreciated.

Edit: Here's the XML of the TextView:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/message"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:text="Do not set time more than 1 hour ahead for 24 hours behind"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/selectedContact" />
```

Comment: Show the xml of the TextView you are trying to rename

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you've completely give us all the error message you get (what are the "Unhandled references"?). But I'll try to answer correctly (I've already had the case once).
Personally, my unhandled reference was a cache file of my builg.gradle : I program in Kotlin and use the plugin (`apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'`) which allows to create automatically the View variables corresponding to the ids of the Views in the xml layout files.
The solution (in this case) is to rename your Textview as you want and then (if necessary) to synchronize your build.gradle.
Hoping to help someone.